# Tidying up double arrows between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to adjust the following (which I have already adjusted from another answer on this site) so that the lines stop short of the nodes, and the arrowheads are bigger/clearer.

Can anyone please help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Syntax:
% \DoublLine[half of the double line distance]{first node}{second node}{options line 1}{options line 2}

\newcommand\DoubleLine[5][3pt]{%   

  \path(#2)--(#3)coordinate[at start](h1)coordinate[at end](h2); 

  \draw[#4]($(h1)!#1!90:(h2)$)--($(h2)!#1!-90:(h1)$); 

  \draw[#5]($(h1)!#1!-90:(h2)$)--($(h2)!#1!90:(h1)$); }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[main_node/.style={circle,fill=green!20,draw,minimum
    size=1em,inner sep=3pt]}]

  \node[main_node] (b) at (0,0) {};

  \node[main_node] (a) at (-1.5, -2)  {};

  \node[main_node] (c) at (1.5, -2) {};

  \DoubleLine{a}{b}{->, dashed}{<-}   

  \DoubleLine{b}{c}{<-,dashed}{->}

  \DoubleLine{a}{c}{->,dashed}{<-}

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

To shorten the paths, use `shorten >= length` and `shorten <= length`. Regarding the arrows issue, you could simply use a different, more visible, arrow tip (using the `arrows.meta` library you could use something like `>=To[scale=1.4]` to enlarge the arrow tip) for further details and arrow tip types, refer to the PGF manual and the `arrows.meta` library; in the following example I used the `Latex` tip arrow for the second diagram.

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\newcommand\DoubleLine[5][3pt]{%   
  \path(#2)--(#3)coordinate[at start](h1)coordinate[at end](h2); 
  \draw[#4]($(h1)!#1!90:(h2)$)--($(h2)!#1!-90:(h1)$); 
  \draw[#5]($(h1)!#1!-90:(h2)$)--($(h2)!#1!90:(h1)$); 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  shorten >= 5pt,
  shorten <= 5pt,
  main_node/.style={
    circle,
    fill=green!20,
    draw,
    minimum size=1em,
    inner sep=3pt
  }
]
\node[main_node] (b) at (0,0) {};
\node[main_node] (a) at (-1.5, -2)  {};
\node[main_node] (c) at (1.5, -2) {};
\DoubleLine{a}{b}{->, dashed}{<-}   
\DoubleLine{b}{c}{<-,dashed}{->}
\DoubleLine{a}{c}{->,dashed}{<-}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  shorten >= 5pt,
  shorten <= 5pt,
  >=Latex,
  main_node/.style={
    circle,
    fill=green!20,
    draw,
    minimum size=1em,
    inner sep=3pt
  }
]
\node[main_node] (b) at (0,0) {};
\node[main_node] (a) at (-1.5, -2)  {};
\node[main_node] (c) at (1.5, -2) {};
\DoubleLine{a}{b}{->, dashed}{<-}   
\DoubleLine{b}{c}{<-,dashed}{->}
\DoubleLine{a}{c}{->,dashed}{<-}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```